# How to resolve a systemd-nspawn container?

Tags: debian, systemd, dns, systemd-nspawn

I have a nspawn container:

```
root@nomad-02:~# machinectl list
MACHINE CLASS     SERVICE        OS     VERSION ADDRESSES
debian  container systemd-nspawn debian 11      192.168.88.171…

1 machines listed.
```

`systemd-resolved.service` is started on the host (and in the container as well):

```
root@nomad-02:~# systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-01-25 22:16:34 UTC; 12h ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 232128 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1132)
     Memory: 5.3M
        CPU: 153ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─232128 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Jan 25 22:16:34 nomad-02 systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Jan 25 22:16:34 nomad-02 systemd-resolved[232128]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Jan 25 22:16:34 nomad-02 systemd-resolved[232128]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Jan 25 22:16:34 nomad-02 systemd-resolved[232128]: Negative trust anchors: 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.arpa 22.172.in-addr.arpa 23.172.>
Jan 25 22:16:34 nomad-02 systemd-resolved[232128]: Using system hostname 'nomad-02'.
Jan 25 22:16:34 nomad-02 systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
```

The container has a vnet:

```
root@nomad-02:~# resolvectl status
Global
         Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign

...

Link 439 (ve-debian)
Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

I would like to know if it is possible to reach the container from within the host using its hostname.

What I tried is:

```
dig @127.0.0.53 debian
```

which does not work.

I can not find any documentation on how to do it. Is it possible to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need the NSS (name service switch, see `man 5 nss`) module "**mymachines**" installed and enabled in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` like this (see `man 8 nss-mymachines`):

```
hosts: mymachines resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] files myhostname dns
```

On Debian, you need the `libnss-mymachines` package, for example.